# what NF stands for in awk?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I know NF is the last element, as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html%60):

*NF is a predefined variable whose value is the number of fields in the current record. awk automatically updates the value of NF each time it reads a record. No matter how many fields there are, the last field in a record can be represented by $NF. So, $NF is the same as $7, which is ‘example.’. If you try to reference a field beyond the last one (such as $8 when the record has only seven fields), you get the empty string. (If used in a numeric operation, you get zero.)*

What it stands for? I guess `NR`, for example, is number, but I'm also not sure about that

Comment: **N**umber of **F**ields?

Comment: ... and `NR` would be **N**umber of **R**ecord

Comment: it was right there and I didn't make the connection :( too tired I guess

Comment: The [`awk(1)` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/awk.1posix.html)